# Windows Server 2008 R2 cluster, MSDTC issue

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, failovercluster, msdtc

We recently installed **MS Windows Server 2008 R2 EE** on two physical **IBM System x3550 M4** server and this cluster hosts Biztalk resources on it. 
**MSDTC** was configured prior to Biztalk resource were added and after Windows Cluster was setup.
Cluster validation reports no issues.
But, if we try to import .MSI packages in Biztalk on active node with all the resources on it it goes well, but the next step with installing the .MSI package on another node fails

```
with the error Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-MSDTC Client 2
Date:          1/21/2014 5:07:58 PM
Event ID:      4104
Task Category: Cluster
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      hostname.company.com
Description:
Failed trying to get the state of the cluster node: MSDTC.The error code returned: 0x80070005
```

It previously did work well, but the only thing which changed is that on one node CNA adapter was replaced, since it was faulty (i.e. new MAC-address).

Deleting the MSDTC resource didn't resolve the issue as suggested [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/06d453d7-f867-4cec-9120-2c6a02f83d57/windows-2008-r2-cluster?forum=winserverClustering).

We are considering reinstalling cluster from scratch since this solution should be delivered shortly and we have lack of time for investigation.

Firewalls are disabled.
No errors in cluster validation report.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling both nodes from scratch, we have got the same error.

Finally the issue was fixed by running the commands below on both nodes:

***-giving Full Access permission on msdtc.log >>***

```
icacls c:\windows\system32\msdtc\msdtc.log /grant "networkservice":F
```

***-giving appropriate permissions for Network Service account to clustered MSDTC service>>***

```
subinacl /service MSDTC$92d91bb1-e731-4c-1688158 /grant="Network Service"=QSETI
```

subinacl should be downloaded separately - [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510).

The meaning of the letters (can be found as well in the subinacl.htm file in the subinacl’s installation folder):

```
Q : Query Service Configuration
S : Query Service Status
E : Enumerate Dependent Services
T : Start Service
I : Interrogate Service
L : Read Control
```